# FFMPEG fixing broken or wrong video containers extensions

Tags: video, ffmpeg, containers

With ffmpeg what is the correct way to fix incorrect file containers.

For example :

We have a ***input.avi*** file but the file should be called ***input.mp4*** because the person who uploaded it has renamed it from ***.mp4*** to ***.avi*** will ffmpeg's copy command fix this for us and allow the ***input.avi*** to keep its ***.avi*** file extension or will it need to become ***.mp4***

Command Line :

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i input.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy output-fixed.avi
```

I read that ffmpeg's stream copy ***-c:v copy -c:a copy*** or ***-vcodec copy -acodec copy*** or ***-c copy*** command should fix any error with any video container.

I just want to fix the file by keeping it in the original file extension it was provided in do not want to change it to be .mp4 if it was not uploaded with that extension.

Comment: If the user simply renamed it why not just rename it again?

Comment: Because I can't tell if they have done and if the copy command what I am running already to fix incorrect time stamps in video containers that get uploaded that have the wrong time stamps fixes this automatically then I should not worry but I have no idea if it is fixing it or not nor do I have any file to test it with what is why I posted here hoping an expert would know or somebody had encountered it before.

Comment: That's a really long sentence. I read it but I have no comprehension of what I just read.

Comment: I suppose rather than trying to explain the situation it's best to just state what I wrote in the question. Will the input.avi being passed through the copy command even though it is not a true .avi file be fine.

Comment: It depends on the formats of the media streams contained in the file. Show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -i input.avi`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a broken media item I can use nor have I found or encountered a problem, I can use windows xcopy command to change the extension but upon all my testing it seems fine, Would there ever will be any case where ffmpeg's copy command would have a problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114795/discussion-between-c0nw0nk-and-lordneckbeard).